# Change schema annotation at runtime accord with some data in a table

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

**The context**

I´m developing a server app to improve the accuracy of the data in a system. We have a system that has several schemas, each schema contains company´s data, one schema per country.
So we had a problem because this companies has the geolocation data a little "disordered". Then we develop a server app that runs some algorithms and fix the data.
We develop this server with Spring and Hibernate.

**The Problem**

We mapped our dtos (our model classes) like this:

`@Entity
@Table(name="company", schema="australia")
public class Company { ... }`

And we have schemas with the same exact structure for usa, new zealand, iraq, etc.

**The question**

How can I implement something to avoid replicate several dtos that will be all the same except by the annotation `schema="aCountry"`

**The ideal solution**

Be capable of change in runtime the schema value accord to some row in a table of countries. IDK if this is possible, but any solution except copy and paste all the classes, and change the `schema` anotation will be take in mind.

Comment: Annotation attributes only accept constant expressions. They cannot be changed at run time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, any alternative? I was thinking that maybe I can extend the Company class and each of the subclasses will have the proper schema anotation. So I have the NewZealandCompany class with the annotation `@Table(name="company" schema="newzealand")` and so on. Is there any way to specify to hibernate that you want make a table per subclass?